# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

i have sql file that i am trying to execute from a perl script like that-

## connect to DB

```
my $dsn = "dbi:Oracle:$ENV{MPR_DB_INSTANCE}";
my $tg_dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$ENV{MPR_DB_USER},$ENV{MPR_DB_PASS},{AutoCommit=>0});
unless ($tg_dbh) {&PrintAndLog("\nDBI connect failed: Unable to connect to database $tg_dbh");} 
print("\nConnected to DB: $ENV{MPR_DB_USER}\@$ENV{MPR_DB_INSTANCE}\n");
    
 print("\nRunning SQL for SY Test\n");
 $sql_statement = $tg_dbh->prepare("$ENV{BIN_PATH}/SY_TG_Test.sql");
 $sql_statement->execute();
 $tg_dbh->commit;
```

I am getting    ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement execute.

any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `prepare` method should be an SQL statement (with placeholders), not a file name.

```
open my $SQL, '<', "$ENV{BIN_PATH}/SY_TG_Test.sql" or die $!;
my $sql_statement = $tg_dbh->prepare(do {local $/; <$SQL>});
```

Comment: @user3720181: Note that you cannot `prepare` more than a single SQL statement, so if your file contains multiple statements you will need a different approach